# Android FileProvider does not work with Google+ Photos

Tags: android, cursor, android-contentprovider, android-fileprovider

I'm trying to use the FileProvider way to display images using Intents. The basic setup is as follows:

```
Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), "my.domain.fileprovider", file);
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setDataAndType(contentUri, "image/*");
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivityForResult(i, Activity.RESULT_OK);
```

It is working fine using the "Gallery" app but "Photos" (Google+) crashes:

```
03-24 11:55:32.390 499-1488/? E/CursorWindow: Failed to read row 0, column 0 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 0 columns.
03-24 11:55:32.400 499-1488/? E/EsAppStartupListener: Uncaught exception in background thread Thread[ImageLoader,5,main]
                                                      java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
                                                          at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
                                                          at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:451)
                                                          at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
                                                          at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:114)
                                                          at mzi.a(PG:103)
                                                          at jhc.t(PG:1399)
                                                          at jhc.c(PG:1376)
                                                          at ksw.handleMessage(PG:293)
                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                          at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
                                                          at ksw.run(PG:280)
03-24 11:55:32.400 499-499/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: ImageLoader
                                               Process: com.google.android.apps.plus, PID: 499
                                               java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
                                                   at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
                                                   at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:451)
                                                   at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
                                                   at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:114)
                                                   at mzi.a(PG:103)
                                                   at jhc.t(PG:1399)
                                                   at jhc.c(PG:1376)
                                                   at ksw.handleMessage(PG:293)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
                                                   at ksw.run(PG:280)
```

Is this a known issue or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: First, don't use a wildcard MIME type. *You* are the one sharing the content. *You* are the one who knows what the MIME type is of that content. Use the real MIME type. Or, do not include a MIME type at all, and the system can ask the `FileProvider` for the MIME type.

Comment: Beyond that, you may need to blend in [my `LegacyCompatCursorWrapper`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider#usage-legacycompatcursorwrapper), which deals with apps that have bugs in how they consume `content:` `Uri` values. [Here is a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider) demonstrating its use.

Comment: Thanks for that CommonsWare. Both setting the MIME type and using your LegacyCompatCursorWrapper did not solve it for me. But after upgrading Google+ "Photos" to the latest version (1.16.0.117494210 as of now) it is working as expected.

Comment: I had similar exception in Google+ Photos app. `LegacyCompatCursorWrapper` helped.